# Open a file on OneDrive using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

I have an Excel file (File #1) in which I would like the VBA code to open a file on my OneDrive (File #2).

Many people will use File #1, so I want it to open File #2 in the background.

I have created a shared link for File #2.  With this link anyone should be able to access the file.

Link: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmdCer05hKV4geAnbDaOSX9UrTfLHQ?e=5Pm7dL

How do I open this File #2 via VBA code in File #1?  **I want it to open in Excel, not Excel on-line**.

I used this code.

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmdCer05hKV4geAnbDaOSX9UrTfLHQ?e=5Pm7dL")
```

When this line of code runs, Excel shuts down and a window opens stating Microsoft Error Reporting.

It then says

> "There was a problem with Microsoft Excel and we apologize for the inconvenience. Microsoft Excel will attempt to recover your work, but recent changes might be lost."

Comment: `Set wb = workbooks.Open( "https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmdCer05hKV4geAnbDaOSX9UrTfLHQ?e=5Pm7dL")`  assuming everyone has the appropriate permissions

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try? Show it.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Yes.  I tried it.  I added the result back to the main body above. It caused the file to close and gave me an error.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
Sub open_excel_from_one_drive()

sfilename = "https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmdCer05hKV4geAnbDaOSX9UrTfLHQ?e=5Pm7dL"
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")
Set xlsheet = xl.Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sfilename, ReadOnly:=True)

End sub
```

The above code works fine for me, but maybe you should change your OneDrive path to be something like that: "https://yourcorp.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/Shared%20Documents/1stfolder/myfile.xlsx"

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If I open it from VBA using the 1drv.ms/... link that it gives to me when I "Share" it, it asks me for a Microsoft login/password that is not my usual Microsoft login. I never found the right password and it's not recoverable.

I solved by using the https://d.docs.live.net/... URL I obtain with a ?ThisWorkbook.fullname in the VBA window. This works without asking a login/password, likely using the account used by the Excel application.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using the below since no other answer on here worked.

`ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmdCer05hKV4geAnbDaOSX9UrTfLHQ?e=5Pm7dL"`

Answer (score -1):

This will let you copy a clear path to the file:

- Go to the sharepoint site where it is saved. Example:
  https://dieboldnixdorf-my.sharepoint.com/
- Locate the file
- Select the 3 dots next to the file
- Select Details
- Scroll down to the "Path" section
- Select the copy option